# Why does adding inputId to my pickerInput segment of my shiny app break my code?

Tags: r, shiny, pickerinput

```
#UI BEGINS
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      pickerInput("chosenplans", "Select State:",
                  #inputId = "stateList",
                  choices = as.character(unique(state_plan_data_filtered$state)),
                  options = list(
                    `actions-box` = TRUE,
                    `live-search` = TRUE),
                  multiple = FALSE,
                  selected = "Alabama"),
      ),
  mainPanel()
  ),
)
```

Whenever I uncomment my inputId, I can't run my Shiny app, and it gives me this error:

**Error in choicesOpt$style : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors**

However, inputId is theoretically an argument for pickerInput. Why can't I explicitly name it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the arguments that `pickerInput` expects are

```
args(pickerInput)
function (inputId, label = NULL, choices, selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE, 
    options = list(), choicesOpt = NULL, width = NULL, inline = FALSE)
```

The value of `"chosenplans"` that you are passing to the function is going to the `inputId=` parameter by default since that's the first unnamed parameter that it woudl match. However when you add `inputId = "stateList"` you seem to be trying to add a second ID, but this now means the value of "chosenplans" will be passed to the first parameter that you haven't already specified which means that will so to the `label=` parameter and `"Select State:"` gets passed to the `chociesOpt=` parameter. THis is not a valid value for `choicesOpt` which is what generates the error.

The the problem is you labeling some parameters and not others and specifying an `inputId=` two different ways which shuffles the parameters around in an unexpected way.

Comment: Ohhhhhh... Thanks for the help!